# What is the best way to compare a string (a) to multiple strings [a,b,c...] in JavaScript? (Without JQuery)

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way? I have added the following to the String.protoype:

```
// str.whereIn(['cat', 'dog, 'mouse']);

String.prototype.whereIn = function(stringArray){
    var a = stringArray.indexOf(this.valueOf());
    return a>-1;
};
```

Comment: [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for example

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: also what is wrong with _indexOf_?

Comment: In single line without creating new variable `return stringArray.indexOf(this.valueOf()) > -1`

Comment: The expected return is a boolean.

Comment: @ssoward You'll get boolean result, the comparison `> -1` returns `true/false`